# How to rotate plotted data?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, rotation

How to rotate the plotted curve about 90 degrees, please? Is it possible to set that the result of ax.plot(x, y, z) should be rotated about 90 degrees? Thank you

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
theta = np.linspace(-4 * np.pi, 4 * np.pi, 100)
z = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
r = z**2 + 1
x = r * np.sin(theta)
y = r * np.cos(theta)
ax.plot(x, y, z, label='parametric curve')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You can control the elevation and azimuth of the camera with `ax.view_init(elev, azim)`, e.g. `ax.view_init(azim=ax.azim+90)`

Comment: It is not possible in the desired direction. Or how to exchange z-axis and y-axis?

Comment: To exchange the z- and y-axis you could change the order of the arguments in your parametric plot, e.g. `ax.plot(x, z, y, label='parametric curve')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advice you to have a look at the rotation matrix. The [topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions) from Wikipedia is a good start! Let's implement it:

We can operate 3 rotations according the 3 axis.

**Workflow**:

- First, we must be sure to deal with radian angle.
- Second, we need to implement the rotation matrix
- Then we compute the rotation using the [`numpy.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)

```
np.array([np.dot(rotation_matrix, vect) for vect in zip(X, Y, Z)])
```

- Finally plot the results

**Full code**:

```
# Modules
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import cos, sin, pi

# Input angles
angle_x = 90
angle_y = 90
angle_z = 90

# Conversion radian
theta_x = angle_x*pi/180
theta_y = angle_y*pi/180
theta_z = angle_z*pi/180

# rotation matrix
R_x = np.array([[1, 0           ,  0           ],
                [0, cos(theta_x), -sin(theta_x)],
                [0, sin(theta_x),  cos(theta_x)]])
R_y = np.array([[ cos(theta_y), 0, sin(theta_y)],
                [ 0           , 1, 0           ],
                [-sin(theta_y), 0, cos(theta_y)]])
R_z = np.array([[cos(theta_z), -sin(theta_z), 0],
                [sin(theta_z),  cos(theta_z), 0],
                [0           ,  0           , 1]])

# Compute initial curve
theta = np.linspace(-4 * np.pi, 4 * np.pi, 100)
Z = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
r = Z**2 + 1
X = r * np.sin(theta)
Y = r * np.cos(theta)

# Compute rotation
rotated_x = np.array([np.dot(R_x, vect) for vect in zip(X, Y, Z)])
rotated_y = np.array([np.dot(R_y, vect) for vect in zip(X, Y, Z)])
rotated_z = np.array([np.dot(R_z, vect) for vect in zip(X, Y, Z)])

# Extras for plotting
def addExtras(ax):
    ax.plot(X, Y, Z, label='Initial curve')
    ax.set_xlabel('X Axis')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y Axis')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z Axis')
    plt.legend()

# Create figure
fig = plt.figure()

# Create subplots 
ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1, projection='3d')
addExtras(ax)

ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 2, projection='3d')
ax.plot(rotated_x[:, 0], rotated_x[:, 1], rotated_x[:, 2], label='X+90° rotation curve')
addExtras(ax)

ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 3, projection='3d')
ax.plot(rotated_y[:, 0], rotated_y[:, 1], rotated_y[:, 2], label='Y+90° rotation curve')
addExtras(ax)

ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 4, projection='3d')
ax.plot(rotated_z[:, 0], rotated_z[:, 1], rotated_z[:, 2], label='Z+90° rotation curve')
addExtras(ax)

# Show results
plt.show()
```

**Output**
[image]